# std::make_pair with float array (float2, unsigned int)

Tags: c++, arrays, std-pair

I have a vector templated with a 'float2, unsigned int'-pair like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<float2, unsigned int>> myVec;
```

And then I'm trying to add such a pair to the vector:

```
unsigned int j = 0;
float2 ab = {1.0, 2.0};
myVec.push_back(std::make_pair(ab, j));
```

This is how I expect it should work, though when I try to compile it I get the error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(163): error C2536: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::first' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=float2 ,
1>              _Ty2=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(166) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::first'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=float2 ,
1>              _Ty2=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\utility(247) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base<float(&)[2],unsigned int&>(_Other1,_Other2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=float2 ,
1>              _Ty2=unsigned int,
1>              _Other1=float (&)[2],
1>              _Other2=unsigned int &
1>          ]
1>          myTest.cpp(257) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<float2(&),unsigned int&>(_Other1,_Other2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=float2,
1>              _Ty2=unsigned int,
1>              _Other1=float2 (&),
1>              _Other2=unsigned int &
1>          ]**strong text**
```

What is the correct way to add this data type to my pair holding vector?

The float2 type is defined as:

```
typedef float        float2[2];
```

Comment: Raw arrays are not very universally usable. For instance, you can't copy-construct a raw array from another one, which is what your code is probably trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ arrays decay to pointers on almost every use. Change `float2`:

```
typedef std::array<float, 2> float2;
```

Or, if you don't have C++11 yet, you can use `boost::array`.

Comment: The float2 is coming from an API, changing that will force me manage the types a lot more. Is there some way I can keep the type as it is yet get the data into a vector as a pair?

Comment: @RoyNieterau You could create your own trivial wrapper type which will contain a `float2` member.

Comment: is it possible to use the std::array and then convert that easily into the float2 (defined by the API). Something as simple as float2 convertedData = float2ArrayData.data(); ?

Comment: @RoyNieterau Depends on the API. Assuming it just takes parameters of type `float2`, you could simply pass `float2ArrayDaya.data()` and it would work.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because arrays can't be copied like regular values.

Ideally you would use something else -- maybe a `std::array` or have your `float2` inside a struct.

If you absolutely have to have a pair of this type, then you can do this:

```
unsigned int j = 0;
float2 ab = {1.0, 2.0};

std::pair<float2,int> new_element;
new_element.first[0] = ab[0];
new_element.first[1] = ab[1];
new_element.second = j;

myVec.push_back(new_element);
```

If you have to do this a lot, you can make a function.  Here is a complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

typedef float float2[2];

std::pair<float2,unsigned int>
  make_pair(const float2 &first,unsigned int second)
{
  std::pair<float2,unsigned int> result;
  result.first[0] = first[0];
  result.first[1] = first[1];
  result.second = second;
  return result;
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  unsigned int j = 0;
  float2 ab = {1.0, 2.0};
  std::vector<std::pair<float2, unsigned int> > myVec;
  myVec.push_back(make_pair(ab, j));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work only in case if `myVec` has  type `std::vector<float*, unsigned>`. Arrays cannot be used in `vector`.

Comment: @soon: It's a vector of pairs, not a vector of arrays.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, seems like I was incorrect(both clang and g++ says, that `std::pair<float2, ...>` is move constructible/assignable). But your example does not compile with clang(while g++ compiles). What could be  wrong?

Comment: @soon: I made a couple of fixes: changed `first[2]` to `first[1]` and changed `>>` to `> >`.  It compiles under clang 3.0 now.

Comment: `>>` isn't a problem for C++11, but even with changes, your code does not compile for me with clang and libc++. [Here](http://pastebin.com/ykWdRBWb) is a log.

Comment: @soon: ok, interesting.  It sounds like a difference between libc++ and libstdc++ then.  My code my actually not be valid for a C++98 library, since with C++98, copying a pair involves passing first and second to the corresponding member initializers; however, with C++11, the copy constructor is explicitly defaulted, so it would be able to do member-wise copy of the array.