# How could type, comprising non move constructible field, be move constructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

<sup>[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814929/stdmake-pair-with-float-array-float2-unsigned-int/) is the root of this question</sup>

I have different behavior while compiling the following code with clang++/libc++ and g++/libstdc++.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using array_t = int[42];
    std::cout << "array_t:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    is_move_constructible: " << std::is_move_constructible<array_t>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    is_move_assignable:    " << std::is_move_assignable<array_t>::value    << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    using pair_t = std::pair<array_t, array_t>;
        std::cout << "pair_t:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    is_move_constructible: " << std::is_move_constructible<pair_t>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "    is_move_assignable:    " << std::is_move_assignable<pair_t>::value    << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    pair_t p1;
    pair_t p2(std::move(p1));

    return 0;
}
```

clang(fails):

```
In file included from /home/soon/Src/C++/main/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:283:11: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
        : first(_VSTD::forward<first_type>(__p.first)),
          ^
/home/soon/Src/C++/main/main.cpp:20:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::pair<int [42], int [42]>::pair' requested here
    pair_t p2(std::move(p1));
           ^
In file included from /home/soon/Src/C++/main/main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:284:11: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
          second(_VSTD::forward<second_type>(__p.second))
          ^
```

g++ compiles without errors. The output is:

```
array_t:
    is_move_constructible: 0
    is_move_assignable:    0

pair_t:
    is_move_constructible: 1
    is_move_assignable:    1
```

I can't determine, which is correct. As I guess, if a class contains non-move-constructible field, it can't be constructed using move technique. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether GCC (or rather libstdc++) is right in allowing this code, but if it is, then the result is correct. The default move constructor will be generated iff all members either have their own move constructor, or are trivially copyable. Pair's move constructor is specified to be defaulted, so it follows these rules. Primitives and arrays of them are trivially copyable.

I suspect that libstdc++ is right, and for some reason you're entering the compiler compatibility branch in libc++ for `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS`, which doesn't support arrays because it doesn't use `= default`. What version of Clang are you using, and are you correctly specifying `-std=c++11`?

Comment: I'm using clang++3.3. Yes, I'm sure, I use `-std=c++11` correctly. Right now I'm looking into standard about requirements for default move constructor. As soon, as I found that, I'll accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Try 12.8/9-11 for the rules. In particular the last bullet of 11.

Answer (score 1):

I should add to Sebastian's answer that clang-3.3 compiles your code w/o problems with the same result (at run-time) as gcc. So the misbehaviour of your version of the clang compiler appears to be a bug, that has been fixed by now.

Comment: Are you sure, you compiling that with `libc++`? Because I have clang++3.3 too.

Comment: @soon clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final) and tip-of-the-trunk libc++

Comment: So, if it is actually fixed, I will not open a ticket in bugtracker. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Type traits can be kind of tricky. `is_move_constructible/assignable` check whether a type contains a move constructor/assignment operator(either explicitly or implicitly defined). That's it. Those type traits won't detect if the actual instantiation of those constructors/operators is ill formed.

Since `std::pair` contains a move constructor/assignment operator, then both `is_move_constructible` and `is_move_assignable` will be `std::true_type`. That only indicates that they're defined, but that doesn't mean that you can actually use them.

This has been discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/pgWYGIvV2Tw).

Comment: A move constructor for `std::pair` must be called, if an argument is `pair_t&&`, isn't that?

Comment: @soon yes, only if that parameter is an xvalue or a prvalue. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Notes).

Comment: But in my code "I actually use them". Look into `pair_t p2(std::move(p1));`. Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: @soon Yes, you're using it. And that's why it's crashing. `std::pair` has a move constructor, but instantiating it for `std::pair<array_t, array_t>` doesn't work, since `array_t` is not movable.

Comment: But it is crashing only with libc++. Using either clang or gcc with libstdc++ does not produce error.